# Launch modal from controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

i'm trying to show a modal window (using jquery ui dialog) to the user from my controller.

For example :

```
def create
  if params[:id]
    #do something
  else
    #show a modal window with a partial as content
end
```

Thx for your help =)

Comment: How you call your create action, by your submit or by a Javascript method

Comment: do you want it like this `if @valid_attributes then save and redirect else render new and show modal form` ??

Comment: That's it. I'm trying to show a modal to create a new thing if the user submits an unknown thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fix, but probably will work for you

Controller

```
def create
  if params[:id]
    #true code
  else
    render :new
    @dialog = true
  end    
end
```

on you new.html.erb

```
<% if @dialog %>
  <%= #dialog code %>
<% else %>
  <%= #normal code %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it works.

**UPDATE**

If what I asked you in comment is correct then you can do this

in your `new.html.erb` you can do this

```
<% form_for @product do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors %>
    <%= #dialog code %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. I already figured this solution but I wanted to find a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show a jQuery dialog from a controller, because you can't execute JavaScript on server side. The closest you could come to this is sending back a JavaScript string to be evaluated on the client side, but this is very bad practice. Your best bet is to key off something on the server side and do your dialog code on the client side. If you don't want a bunch of JavaScript in your erb templates, you can call a function from there, or you can do your submit via AJAX and either have your handler do the dialog or render a js.erb template that can both render partials and do JavaScript. Let me know if you want an example of any of the above and I'll see if I can provide one.

Comment: Well i m interested to see the cleanest way to do this, and also DRYest way :) thx for ur time